# Resolving type ambiguity with non-primitive types

Tags: regex, haskell, types, web-scraping

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to resolve this type ambiguity in the following code. I'm trying to use the library Text.HTML.Scalpel to get all  elements with an href attribute that satisfies a regex.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8  as B8
import           Data.List
import           Network.HTTP.Simple
import           Text.HTML.Scalpel.Core
import           Text.Regex.Posix

main :: IO ()
main = do
  content <- fetchUrlBody "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_American_institutions_of_higher_education"
  print $ scrapeStringLike content getStateListings

fetchUrl :: Request -> IO (Response B8.ByteString)
fetchUrl req = httpBS req

fetchUrlBody :: Request -> IO (B8.ByteString)
fetchUrlBody req = fmap getResponseBody $ fetchUrl req

getStateListings :: Scraper B8.ByteString [B8.ByteString]
getStateListings =
  attrs "href" ("a" @: ["href" @=~ "[^/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_]"])
```

Gives the the following error:

```
     Ambiguous type variable re0 arising from a use of @=~
      prevents the constraint (RegexLike re0 String) from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what re0 should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        instance RegexLike Regex String
          -- Defined in Text.Regex.Posix.String
     In the expression:
        "href" @=~ "[^/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_]"
      In the second argument of (@:), namely
        ["href" @=~ "[^/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_]"]
      In the second argument of attrs, namely
        ("a"
            @: ["href" @=~ "[^/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_]"])
   |
23 |   attrs "href" ("a" @: ["href" @=~ "[^/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_]"])
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've tried various things including changing troublesome line to:

```
getStateListings :: Scraper B8.ByteString [B8.ByteString]
getStateListings =
  attrs "href" ("a" @: ["href" @=~ (makeRegex "[^/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_]" :: Regex)])
```

Which seems to satisfy re0 in the RegexLike constraint, but now it needs the source type also. I have no idea how to specify a type annotation such that the regex is of type `RegexLike Regex ByteString`. The new error is:

```
     Ambiguous type variable source0 arising from a use of makeRegex
      prevents the constraint (RegexMaker
                                  Regex CompOption ExecOption source0) from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what source0 should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption B8.ByteString
          -- Defined in Text.Regex.Posix.ByteString
        instance RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption String
          -- Defined in Text.Regex.Posix.String
        ...plus two instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
     In the second argument of (@=~), namely
        (makeRegex "[^/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_]" ::
            Regex)
      In the expression:
        "href"
          @=~
            (makeRegex "[^/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_]" ::
               Regex)
      In the second argument of (@:), namely
        ["href"
            @=~
              (makeRegex "[^/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_]" ::
                 Regex)]
   |
23 |   attrs "href" ("a" @: ["href" @=~ (makeRegex "[^/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_]" :: Regex)])
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I don't know about the type error, but your regex is wrong. What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: Any string starting with wiki/list... I added the brackets after seeing a Haskell regex example somewhere.

Comment: OK, you need to remove the brackets then.

Comment: You could try turning off the monomorphism restriction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The incantation should be

```
"href" @=~ (makeRegex ("^/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_" :: String) :: Regex)
```

`@=~` is polymorphic in its argument type, so you need `:: Regex` to nail it down. There is no `IsString Regex`, so you need to use `makeRegex`. `makeRegex` is extremely polymorphic. Its return type is already nailed down with `:: Regex`, so just you need to give its argument a `:: String` to get past `-XOverloadedStrings`'s polymorphism.

You can clean up this mess with

```
regex :: String -> Regex
regex = makeRegex

"href" @=~ regex "^/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_"
```